# Power Apps: Storing Information and Sending it Through Email

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I am using Microsoft Power Apps to create a digital training sign off sheet in which data of a trainee must be stored and once filled out, that data must be sent via email to the trainer as a sort of confirmation of completion.

I understand how to create and send an email on the press of a button but I am having difficulty sending the information I need.

I need to be able to send the name of the employee (which is entered in a textbox, as well as what the trainee selected through the checkbox).

Here is a screenshot to better understand:[image]
If you can help at any part of this it is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to make sure you're not resetting the inputs before you send the email. Essentially you don't want to clear your information before the email action can send.

If the current user is getting the email sent to themselves you can access the current user's email by using User().Email

To access the users selected content from the checkboxes, you have to write out the name of the checkbox with a ".Selected.Value" or ".Text" after it.

Try something like this:

```
Navigate(xxxx);
Office365Outlook.SendEmailV2(
  User().Email,
  "Email Subject",
  "Email body beginning" & checkbox1.Selected.Text & "email body ending."
);
Reset(xxxx);
Reset(xxxx);
```